# Simple selection_sort in C

Tags: algorithm, c, sorting

I study algorithms, and I try to implement each algorithm in C
(Perhaps it would be better to choose C++, but okay)

Here is my implementation of sorting by choice. How would you rate it?

To be honest, I'm a bit intimidated by malloc and whether I used it correctly. (returning an array from a function is not that easy)

Here is code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int *selection_sort(int *arr, int size)
{
    int small = arr[0]; 
    int small_index = 0; 
    int swap;

    int* n_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
        }
        n_arr[i] = arr[i];
    }

    return n_arr;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int size = 5;
    int arr[] = {5, 3, 6, 2, 10};
    int *n_arr = selection_sort(arr, size);
    if (n_arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", n_arr[i]);
        }
    }
    free(n_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S** I have not yet figured out how to make the code work elegantly with any array (now I have to change the size and the array data themselves)

Comment: I see neither *choice* nor *selection sort* - `small_index` never being used should be a hint. I see a `malloc()`, but no documentation it is used. Consequently, there is no `free()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Test for Possible Memory Allocation Errors

In modern high-level languages such as C++, memory allocation errors throw an exception that the programmer can catch. This is not the case in the C programming language. While it is rare in modern computers because there is so much memory, memory allocation can fail, especially if the code is working in a limited memory application such as embedded control systems. In the C programming language when memory allocation fails, the functions `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` return `NULL`. Referencing any memory address through a `NULL` pointer results in **undefined behavior** (UB).

Possible unknown behavior in this case can be a memory page error (in Unix this would be call Segmentation Violation), corrupted data in the program and in very old computers it could even cause the computer to reboot (corruption of the stack pointer).

To prevent this **undefined behavior** a best practice is to always follow the memory allocation statement with a test that the pointer that was returned is not NULL.

```
    int* n_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    if (n_arr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: selection_sort malloc() failed\n");
        return n_arr;
    }
```

## Convention When Using Memory Allocation in C

When using malloc(), calloc() or realloc() in C a common convention is to sizeof(*PTR) rather sizeof(PTR_TYPE), this make the code easier to maintain and less error prone, since less editing is required if the type of the pointer changes.

```
    int* n_arr = malloc(sizeof(*n_arr) * size);
```

## Prefer `calloc()` Over `malloc()` for Arrays

The `calloc()` memory allocation function is primarily for empty arrays, the memory it provides has previous content removed. The memory returned by all the allocation functions is from the `heap` and may have been used previously there is no guarantee that the contents will not have values.

## The Code May Attempt to Free a Null pointer

The code in main() calls `free()` even if the pointer returned from `selection_sort()` is null, it would be better to move the `free()` into the compound statement of the if.

Comment: To avoid confusion: it's perfectly fine to call `free()` on a NULL pointer, but if you are already checking for it to be NULL anyway, you can avoid the cost of the useless call.

Comment: @G.Sliepen It is true that `free()` works properly on a NULL pointer now, but it used to be a great way to cause a Segmentation Violation on BSD Unix and System V Unix (Pre ANSI C or even early ANSI C). I tried to phrase the statement so that it didn't indicate free would cause an error but I guess I missed.

Comment: thx for answer! It's funny that such a simple program uses so many nuances.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Disagree with preferring `calloc()` over `malloc()` when code simply assigns each `n_arr[i]` in turn.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@pacmaninbw](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278821/29485) review:

**Well formatted**

**Coding goal**

`selection_sort(int *arr, int size)` adjusts `arr` contents, allocates data and returns a copy of `arr`.  Seems like skipping the allocation altogether and just adjusting/sorting `arr` would be sufficient.

**Useless code**

These 2 lines serve no purpose.

```
int small = arr[0]; 
int small_index = 0;
```

**Documentation**

`selection_sort()` deserves at least a few notes in code as to what it does.

**`size == 0`**

If `size <= 0`, `int small = arr[0];` is a problem.

Better to not assume `size > 0`.  Instead test it.

```
int *selection_sort(int *arr, int size) {
  if size > 0) { // add
    int small = arr[0]; 
    ...
  }
}
```

**`int` vs `size_t` for array sizing**.

`int` is insufficient for very large arrays.  `size_t` is designed to well handle all array indexing and sizing.

```
// int *selection_sort(int *arr, int size)
int *selection_sort(int *arr, size_t size)
```

**Parameter order**

Less common yet useful to self document and allow for certain parametric analyzers, put the size first.  `arr` remains a pointer, yet clear that `size` is the expected range to use with `arr`.

```
// int *selection_sort(int *arr, int size)
int *selection_sort(int size, int arr[size])
```

**Declare where needed**

Rather than declare objects far away from their use.  Declare more locally.

```
int *selection_sort(int *arr, int size) {
    int small = arr[0]; 
    int small_index = 0; 
    // int swap;
    ...
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                // swap = arr[i];
                int swap = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = swap;
            }
```

**Simplify maintenance**

Instead of trying to coordinate `size` and the `arr` initialization list length, let the the 5 come from a calculation.

```
// int size = 5;
int arr[] = {5, 3, 6, 2, 10};
int size = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
```

**Unused arguments**

`argc` and `argv` are not used in `main()`.  Well enabled compiler may warn about unused arguments.  Do not declare them or `(void)` them to clearly show they are not used.

```
//int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;
```

**`const` in `char const *argv[]` is unusual**

I suspect it's OK - looks odd.  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is far more common.

**Allocation style**

Consider `p = malloc(sizeof p[0] * n)`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// int* n_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
int* n_arr = malloc(sizeof n_arr[0] * size);
```

Comment: thx! veru useful feedback for me!

Answer (score 0):

#### Not selection sort

This is not a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  This is an exchange sort.  It's closest to [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or [I can't believe it can sort](https://blog.adacore.com/i-cant-believe-that-i-can-prove-that-it-can-sort).

Selection sort is quadratic in comparisons but linear in assignments.  So it is good when assignments are expensive but comparisons are cheap.  E.g. sorting a file in place.

This is quadratic in both comparisons and assignments.  And it doesn't even engage in the one optimization that bubble sort offers; it doesn't stop checking if the list is sorted.  With that optimization, bubble sort offers superior sorting of data that is sorted or almost sorted.  Because one can verify that a list is sorted in linear time.

Like a selection sort, this puts the minimum value from [`i`, `size`) in the `i` position after the `i + 1` pass.  The difference is that selection sort does one swap.  This will potentially do `size - i` swaps on each pass.

On the bright side, this doesn't sort backwards at first, like I-can't-believe-it-can-sort.

#### This modifies the input

So you do two things that are contradictory.

1. You modify the input, changing its order.
2. You create a new copy.

Usually you would do one or the other of these.  Either you modify the input or you create a new copy (so as to avoid modifying the input).  You do both.  So you get all the negatives of both but the benefits of neither.

Negatives of modifying the input:

1. Can't take constant input.
2. Impossible to recover the original order.

Negatives of making a new copy:

1. Uses more space.
2. May fail.
3. Requires `free` to release the new copy when finished.

Comment: (Not exactly `bubble sort`: [Exchange sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Exchange_sort).)